# Determining Normality With Large Samples

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, matlab, sampling-theory

I am taking in some files and I must determine if the data sets are normally distributed (yes, within a certain degree of certainty because it cannot be proven only disproven). My data sets are quite large. Most are over 15,000 samples. What is a good test to run? I would rather not sample them at random and instead use the whole data set. Also, if possible, do you know how to do this in matlab? I can type out a method if need be, but it would be nice to use a preset function. Thanks.

Comment: You may want to try to ask this at http://stats.stackexchange.com, but most likely you don't need a normality test at all. What's the purpose of performing it in your particular case? With large datasets, even the smallest deviations for normality will be detected, so the results may not be very useful. I'd start by calculating the skewness and kurtosis of the data. Normal distributions have 0 as skewness and 3 as kurtosis, so, depending on how "rigorous" you want to be, you may choose some "acceptable boundaries" around those values

Comment: I want to prove that I can use a kalman filter with the data. If the data is normal than I can use the filter freely otherwise I must use a more robust filter. Sometimes my skewness and kurtosis is less than ten but in general it is large.

Comment: If you have data, it is not normal.  No test needed.  For your particular objective (which you haven't given) you'll need to state what sort of departure that is free of the effect of sample size.  For example, are "departures" in the tail regions more important than in the middle of the distribution?  If you use a standard test, then you're saying that this test somehow knows what you consider to be a departure from normality.  Statisticians are great but not mind readers.  You should follow @David 's advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the reason in @David's Comment most tests of normality
don't accommodate samples of size larger than a few
thousand. Real data tend to have small deviations from
normality, which are not of consequence for the validity of statistical procedures, so there is no point in detecting anomalies that would be evident only in very large samples.

In R, here is how to sample $n = 15000$ observations
from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 100, \sigma = 15).$ For data
sampled in R, one would not expect detectable differences from normality, up to the accuracy
of double precision representation of the data.

```
set.seed(2019) # for reproducibility
x = rnorm(15000, 200, 15)
```

A summary of the data shows the sample mean and median about equal and first and third quartiles about equidistant from the median---as one would expect from normal data.

```
summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  37.37   89.61   99.72   99.67  109.68  160.71
```

Also a histogram of the data on a density scale (so that the areas of all histogram bars sum to unity) is well-matched by a normal density curve with $\mu$ approximated by sample mean $\bar X$ and $\sigma$ approximated by sample standard deviation $S.$

```
hist(x, prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2")
mu.est = mean(x);  sg.est = sd(x)
curve(dnorm(x, mu.est, sg.est), add=T, lwd=2, col="red")
```

[image]

The Shapiro-Wilk test of normality can handle up to 5000 observations. We can test three blocks of 5000.
After the first test, we use `$`-notation to show only
the P-value of each test. If the P-value exceeds 0.05, we say that data are consistent with sampling from a normal population, but that is no proof that the data are perfectly normal.

```
shapiro.test(x[1:5000])

        Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  x[1:5000]
W = 0.9996, p-value = 0.4131

shapiro.test(x[5001:10000])$p.val
[1] 0.7028041
shapiro.test(x[10001:15000])$p.val
[1] 0.5594307
```

We can also sample random subsets of size 5000 (without replacement), and test them:

```
shapiro.test(sample(x,5000))$p.val
[1] 0.9059113
shapiro.test(sample(x,5000))$p.val
[1] 0.7519748
```

Furthermore, a good overview of the normality of the entire sample of 15000 can be had by looking at a normal probability plot.

```
qqnorm(x);  qqline(x, col="red", lwd=2)
```

[image]

The excellent fit to a straight line between theoretical
quantiles $\pm 3$ indicates excellent fit of the data to a normal distribution. [There are not enough data points in the tails to overcome the randomness of sampling, so don't expect more than an approximate fit beyond $\pm 3.]$

Not all of these tests and descriptions of the data are
necessary to check that there is no important departure
from normality. You might pick ones you understand
best from a theoretical point of view or ones with
the greatest intuitive appeal.  But do not expect
data from real-life applications to show as good a
fit to normality as those generated by trustworthy
statistical software.